# Can't cross compile opengl program with mingw

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, mingw, cross-compiling

I want to compile program for windows from debian

```
> '/opt/mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++' '/home/redrockfish/Projects/OpenGl0/main.cpp' -o arcanoid.exe -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglut32

/tmp/ccrvQIKM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
/tmp/ccrvQIKM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
/tmp/ccrvQIKM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
/opt/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrvQIKM.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

if I remove `-lglut32` the number of underfined references increases. header if freeglut.h, taken from official website. replacing glut32 with glut, adding -lGLU didn't help. with -lGL

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What's up with that `/opt` path?  Debian's `mingw-w64-i686-dev` package sticks most files under `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32`.

Comment: ive downloaded it manually from the source forge

Comment: In Windows the OpenGL interface library is called `opengl32` not `GL` so you have to link with `-lopengl32` (it's always …32, even when targeting 64 bit systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like `__glutCreateWindowWithExit` are not part of the official [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut-3.spec.pdf) API. Actually, that function is an extension made by [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net) (and not even part of their external API), so you must not link some random GLUT DLL, but a freeglut one (which are available for windows).

Comment: i downloaded freeglut libs precompiled for mingw from the of site and that worked, thanks